# Specify the local port to used in tcpClient?

Tags: c#

I have the follow code for comunication with the Server in TCP

```
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.250", 2021);
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            string textToSend = "READ#TEST#EXECUTOR";
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            if (client.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
            {
                var bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                nwStream.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); //the message incoming
                Debug.WriteLine($"{msg}");
            }
```

But the answer is 192.168.0.82 (My Address PC) port 57679, port 57722, ...
The local port is random and I want to port 15201 for successed communication.
How can I specify the local port?

Comment: `TcpClient` has no support for that (and it is an unusual scenario -- normally the local port is irrelevant). You'll have to manually create a `Socket` and call `Socket.Bind`. A `NetworkStream` can then be created on top of that socket.

Comment: @JeroenMostert https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-tcpclient-ctor(system-net-ipendpoint)

Comment: @Charlieface: Oh, that's weird. I read right past that constructor, assuming it would be specifying a remote endpoint. Sometimes the fact that constructors aren't explicitly named is a real drawback.

Comment: Thank you Charlieface, with the Socket everything works.
Socket.Bind it's the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the local end point in the constructor. Confusingly, if you pass `host` and `port` it refers to the *remote* endpoint, but if you pass `IPEndPoint` it's the *local* endpoint. You then connect separately using `Connect` or `ConnectAsync`.

Further improvements:

- Add missing `using` blocks.
- Use `async` `await` wherever possible.
- Use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` to avoid messing with encodings and byte arrays.

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 15201)))
{
    await client.ConnectAsync("192.168.0.250", 2021);
    using (NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nwStream, Encoding.ASCII, leaveOpen: true))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nwStream, Encoding.ASCII, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        string textToSend = "READ#TEST#EXECUTOR";
        await writer.WriteAsync(textToSend);
        await writer.FlushAsync();  // make sure to flush or close the writer so that receiver gets whole message
        string msg = await reader.ReadLineAsync(); // alternatively ReadToEndAsync
        Debug.WriteLine($"{msg}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also tested this solution successfully, in my opinion it should be the best.