# NetworkStream.Read return zero

Tags: c#, networkstream

When I send a small message up to 64KB it works correct and  returns the number of bytes.
When I send a large message,  returns zero

Client

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1",21);
stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] dataToSend= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);//large message 1MB or more
stream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length );
stream.Flush();
```

Server

```
byte[] array = new byte[1024];
var readBytes = stream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
```

Comment: Side notes: You are missing `using` on `client` and `stream`, also consider using `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader`. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/73152289/14868997

Comment: Your solution works fine for small msg but returns an error for large msg

System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine..

Comment: I showed a similar solution for someone sending >2GB file, and they were happy with that https://stackoverflow.com/a/73036755/14868997. In that case the file is opened then copied directly to the `NetworkStream` using `await fileStream.CopyToAsync(stream);`. Possibly something like a firewall or antivirus is getting in the way.

Comment: Your code worked correctly in .NET 6, but not in .Net Standard 2.0. In .NET 6 it sends as TCP and in Standard as FTP

Comment: Sorry but a `NetworkStream` is just a simple stream over TCP, there is no application level protocol here. FTP is itself an application layer protocol, which works over TCP, and `NetworkStream` does not do that. In fact, there is no real support for FTP in .NET outside of the deprecated `WebRequest` class

Comment: I created a small application with your code. It works well. I'm going to find out why the my application doesn't. Thanks for help.

Comment: My problem was solved by changing the port from 21 to another